# Displaying a string unescaped in IRB or in general

Tags: ruby, string, character-encoding, terminal, irb

Suppose I have a string `"this\n\tis \"helpful\""` and I'd like it to be displayed in the terminal, unescaped, for copy/paste reasons, i.e.

```
this
  is "helpful"
```

Is this possible in terminal, either in IRB or otherwise?

Comment: Try this `puts "this\n\tis \"helpful\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
11:15:14lasto1.9.3 ~/clients    irb
1.9.3-p448 :001 > s = "this\n\tis \"helpful\""
 => "this\n\tis \"helpful\""
1.9.3-p448 :002 > puts s
this
    is "helpful"
 => nil
1.9.3-p448 :003 >
```

Comment: Ha, of course!  I feel really dumb now.  I was using `p` instead of `put`.